# Does coverslip thickness matter for high NA oil immersion objectives?

Tags: optics, refraction, microscopy

This question is related to [Impact of covering glass on lens performance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11978/impact-of-covering-glass-on-lens-performance).

I use a 63x TIRF objective with a numerical aperture of 1.46 and oil immersion.
The immersion oil has an index of $n_e=1.518$.
I'm observing green eGFP fluorescence at around 510 nm.
Does it matter if I use a coverslip (BK7 glass) with 140 $\mu$m thickness instead of 170 $\mu$m?

Edit: The objective is a Zeiss Objective alpha "Plan-Apochromat" 63x/1.46 Oil Corr M27

[image: Zeiss Objective]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are getting a bit higher aberrations in the corners of the image (i.e. they might be a little more blurry).

As long as image quality is ok for you, you may continue doing so.

Comment: I am more concerned about the spherical (and maybe chromatic) aberration which would effect the PSF and Strehl ratio. My field of view is very small, 60$\mu$m diameter.

Comment: Do you have specific model of your lens? Do you know it's type or optical scheme (might be in the docs)? I might then try to simulate coverglass effect (and knowing model/optical scheme would make simulation more precise, but possible in any way)

Comment: I added a screenshot from their web store but I'm afraid they wouldn't give me exact information. A while ago I searched through their patents but I think the objective is too new for the patent to be released (if there even is one).

Comment: Whoa, nice lens price :-) While I am still thinking should I spend 1200$ for whole 'decent' microscope :-)

Comment: Hmm... This adjustable ring seems to be something interesting... Isn't it have adjustable glass correction? :-)

Comment: Yes 0.150 to 0.190 mm it says. But this is quite hard to adjust because it changes the focus also I don't know if I have to use the red or black indication on the scale.

Comment: As far as I see it, it does have a tick for 0.14, so you should be able to perfectly set this lens for your glass... As for the focus change - this is another question, which should be easier to solve :-) What scale you are talking about?

Comment: @BarsMonster let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/767/discussion-between-whoplisp-and-barsmonster)